# How can I prevent SASS variables from being overwritten in Foundation?

Tags: sass, zurb-foundation, bower

I have installed Foundation SASS using Bower. Then I have imported foundation and initialized it by the following commands on my `main.scss`:

```
@import "../vendor/foundation-sites/scss/foundation.scss";
@include foundation-everything(true); // Init the foundation
```

The problem is that, there's a setting file, `_settings.scss`,  that foundation.scss import which I need to override. Since I shouldn't touch the files inside Bower directory,`vendor/`, I need to make those changes on my `main.scss`. And no, the `_settings.scss` doesn't make use of the `!default` functionality. A snippet of how the settings are defined is as follows:

```
$global-font-size: 100%;
$global-width: rem-calc(1200);
$global-lineheight: 1.5;
```

Is there any way I can define a variable before the include just so that it doesn't ever get overwritten? Something like..

```
$global-font-size: 16px !important;
$global-width: 1000px !important;
$global-lineheight: 1 !important;    
@import "../vendor/foundation-sites/scss/foundation.scss";
@include foundation-everything(true); // Init the foundation
```

Comment: You should be editing these value from within the `_settings.scss` file. Is there a reason you do not want to do that?

Comment: I've installed it using Bower, so suppose there is an update in the future, whatever is in that folder will be overwritten. So, to avoid that, I am making any overrides on my `main.css`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Two cases, two way :

## You must maintain a package in bower

I will use [symbolic link](http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/unix-creating-symbolic-link-ln-command/) to make things easy. Take a look about my project files.

- I have install foundation with bower :

  ```
  bower_component/foundation/scss/{...whatever}.scss
  ```
- Then I would create a symlink to .bower_component/foundation/scss folder.

  ```
  src/scss/foundation        # this is a symbolic link to -> ./bower_component/foundation/scss
  ```
- And I copy files I want to customize out of bower_component.

  ```
  src/scss/my_settings.scss  # copied from foundation/scss folder
  ```
- And I add my own scss.

  ```
  src/scss/main.scss
  ```

  which import all my customization and foundation.scss all together

  ```
  @import 'my_settings' ;
  @import '...other_customization...'
  @import 'foundation/foundation' ;
  ```
- Then build `src/scss/main.scss`, and everything works well.

Then you can maintain foundation version with bower without worries. No matter what changes in `bower_components/foundation`, just make sure the folder name and relative path is right, everything will be fine.

---

## Well, the version is not so important.

Ask yourself a question. What benefit you with foundation being maintained by bower? If there is no good reason for you, you could just move foundation out of bower_component folder and do any change you want.

> Bower doesn't prescribe to the user its own build system, or to the
>   developer a method of including libraries (AMD, CommonJS, etc.) All
>   **Bower does is install the right versions of the packages that the
>   project needs and their dependencies.** In other words: it downloads
>   source files for the right libraries and everything they need into a
>   special folder. **Everything else is up to the developer**.
>   Quoted from : [Artem Sapegin](http://frontendbabel.info/articles/bower-why-frontend-package-manager/)